# Rails functional tests fail for MongoDB with ActiveRecord/SQLite3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid with Rails but all of the functional tests that have been generated are failing with an error similar to:

```
test_should_get_new(PostsControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: comments: DELETE FROM "comments"
```

These are the tests that are generated:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @post = posts(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  [...]
end
```

Am I supposed to change the tests? Or remove some reference to ActiveRecord or Sqlite? (I still have sqlite in my gemfile because I had issues removing it and am still unsure about how to completely remove it from the app since I'm not using it for anything)

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb`, remove `require "rails/all"` and add

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

In `config/development.rb` comment / remove the following:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

In `config/test.rb` comment / remove the following:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

If it's not working, can you show me your `spec_helper.rb` please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you type

```
rails --help
```

then the option to skip Active Record is listed

```
-O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
```

I suggest that you create a new Rails project using this option to remove all vestiges of Active Record, including all of the pieces that Pierre-Louis mentioned, plus others like test fixtures, then recreate/reimport your model and test code.